# all_frames:true not working for stackoverflow snippet output window

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension, sandbox

I created an extension I want to inject into all frames with this manifest:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "js": ["myscript.js"],
        "matches": ["*://*/*"],
        "all_frames": true,
        "run_at": "document_start",
        "match_about_blank": true
    }
],
```

For the sake of this question, suppose `myscript.js` only has:

```
console.log('------------------------------------');
console.log(window);
console.log('------------------------------------');
```

When I try this it works well, i.e. if I try on Gmail I can see that many iframes keep getting loaded as I use the site and each time I get the script injected properly and and see above lines in the code.

However I found one exception which I can't understand. If I open the snippet editor here on StackOverflow, the result pane which is an iframe does not get injected into (i.e. I do not see the lines in the console).

What is going on? And how can I inject into the snippet result window as well?

Comment: Sites often create a blank iframe, then fill it with stuff. See "match_about_blank" in the documentation.

Comment: thx! but no that didn't solve it (edited my answer)

Comment: Did you reload the extension on chrome://extensions page?

Comment: yes I also just tried removing and reinstalling it as well, does it work for you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual `iframe` you're referring to has the following form:

```html
<iframe      id="snpte-box-edit-result"
           name="789af52f-65c6-4c71-b52f-66063e29d6f3"
        sandbox="allow-forms allow-modals allow-scripts"
          class="snippet-box-edit"
    frameborder="0">
```

Quote from [Content scripts documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#match_about_blank) for `match_about_blank`:

> Content scripts cannot be inserted in sandboxed frames.

So, unfortunately, this will be an exception you cannot "break into".

Comment: Looks like this is not the case anymore, the link does not mentions anything about sandboxed iframes

Comment: @S.j.Sakib Might be the result of https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=55084